# What is the best way to feed data from Oracle Golden Gate to Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, oracle-golden-gate

I am looking forward to streaming data into BQ from OGG. What is the best way to do it? Can data from Oracle Golden Gate be streamed directly into BigQuery or do we need some connectors?

Please suggest the best possible way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a connector to bridge the 2 worlds:

- Either a bridge that convert OGG event into PubSub messages, and then process the PubSub message in streaming (with [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtobigquery) or with [Cloud Run/Cloud Functions if the data volume and rate are acceptable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-go)).
- Or listen OGG with a compute (On prem or on GCP) and for each message, stream write the data into BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am new to OGG and need to know if we need to use third party connector or is it possible that we do it entirely using GCP services.I am apprehensive to use any third party tools.How  do we listen OGG with a compute on GCP.Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I would add ETL article - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/performing-etl-from-relational-database-into-bigquery and BigQuery data integration - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers. Take a look at Alooma.

Comment: You can process your OGG messages like a JMS queue. Here the [Oracle documentation for that](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/gg121211/gg-adapter/GADAD/intro_adapter.htm#GADAD101). I never tried this kind of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

as a heads-up, the GoldenGate product is natively certified to deliver data into Google Big Query, the full list of big data certifications for GG 19c is here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ogg-19-1-0-0-0-cert-matrix-5491855.xls

(note; you can replicate data from Oracle DB 11.2.0.4 and higher, using OGG 12.3 and higher, into GG Big Data 19c for Big Query)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle GoldenGate has a native adapter to deliver to Google BigQuery. It is been there in market since Sept 2018 and used successfully by many companies.
Refer to https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/goldengate-for-big-data-123211-release-update

I think Google Pub/Sub is not the right interface to deliver large volume of data into cloud. Google Pub/Sub has limitations on throughput.
See this link https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas.

Please note that GoldenGate does not have any true limitations or boundaries like Google Pub/Sub or AWS Kinesis. GoldenGate is a true scalable product.

Use cases of failure using Google Pub/Sub could be as follows:

What happens if the input speed is more than 5MB/sec? Pub/Sub will deny
data and how should that failure be handled?
One might argue that they will create multiple topics, but what if there is a main table that is creating more than 5MB/sec and you don't want to segregate into different topics?